# Using InstantTaskExecutorRule causes java.lang.RuntimeException in junit test

Tags: android, android-room, android-testing, android-livedata

I am unit-testing a library that uses a `RoomDatabase`. Unit-testing the `RoomDatabase` itself was done using `InstantTaskExecutorRule` so that `LiveData` updates can occur instantaneously:

```
@Rule public TestRule rule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

And that works fine. However, when unit-testing the library which calls the database, using the same rule causes the test to throw the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Is there any reason why `InstantTaskExecutorRule` works on the underlying database DAOs but not a library calling them?

Comment: Do you also use something like [`MainCoroutineRule`](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/89becf6025b9caedcbc669138379f21ada02a659/app/src/sharedTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/MainCoroutineRule.kt). I believe it might help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I am also unit testing a RoomDatabase with Robolectric and the same error occurs while using

```
@get:Rule
val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

I simply removed it and I'm using *runBlocking{ ... }* in my tests like this example :

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun `test insert and retrieve text`() {
    runBlocking {
        dao.insertText("some text")
        assertEquals("some text",dao.getText())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of causing this error is a missing ".allowMainThreadQueries()" when building your database:

> database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
> ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
> myDatabase::class.java
> )
> .allowMainThreadQueries()
> .build()

(Also, testing with databases is recommended to be done as instrumented tests as local tests will use a default SQLite version instead of the version your app is actually using.)